Is it possible to send whattsapp messages to a whattsapp group
I'd need to be able to send birthday greetings to a whattsapp group (about 50 users) by twilio but could'nt find a clear way to achieve this. I got the info to send such message to a single whattsapp account but is not clear to me how to reach a wattsapp group instead of a single user and wonder if this is actually feasible.

Unfortunately, this is, as of now, not supported by the Meta WhatsApp API. Hence, it's also not possible with the Twilio WhatsApp API.
